# Unable to pass integer array as argument to function whose local argument is character pointer

Tags: c, casting, pointer-arithmetic

I have a `main` function that declares an integer array. I want to pass this array to a function whose parameter is of type `char *`.  I cannot alter the signature of the called function.

My aim is to copy the contents of `main`'s integer array `data1` into `disp`'s integer array `data2`, but when I try the following code, I get incorrect values.
data2[0]= 10,data2[1]= 0,data2[2]= 0,data2[3]= 0,data2[4]= 20.

How can I correct it to yield data2[0]= 10,data2[1]= 20,data2[2]= 30,data2[3]= 40,data2[4]= 50 ?

**Note:** It is not mandatory that `data2` be the same size as `data1`. It could be the same size or larger. I expect the first five elements of `data2` to end up the same as the corresponding elements of `data1`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void disp(char *buffer)
{
    int itr, data2[5];
    for(itr=0;itr<5;itr++)
    {
        data2[itr]=(int*)buffer[itr];
        printf("data2[%d]= %d\n",itr,data2[itr]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int data1[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
    disp((char*)data1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you cast the passed `int` pointer to a `char` pointer and then recasting it to a pointer to `int` inside of `disp` again?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio actually data I am passing is of integer one but in disp function it is consider as character. so I thought to cast it as pointer to int

Comment: @user3559780, the question is why the argument to `buffer` is declared as a `char *` at all.  If you expect it to be an `int *` then why aren't you just declaring it as one in the first place?

Comment: Array indexing has higher precedence than cast, so you aren't casting `buffer`, you are casting `buffer[itr]`, which makes no sense.

Comment: @user3559780 If your problem has been solved, feel free to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which was the most helpful one or solved your problem. With this you pay something to the author of this answer for his effort back, your future questions are more attractive to get an answer and you help SO to keep a clear place by showing others the problem is solved. Thank you for your collaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function call seems not to be the problem.  You are permitted to cast `data1` to type `char *` as you do, and as is needful for matching the type of the function parameter.  This is in fact a special case in that it is even allowed to access the pointed-to data via the resulting `char *`.

The problem is in reading the data back out inside `disp()`.  This statement:

> ```
>         data2[itr]=(int*)buffer[itr];
> ```

is broken because the indexing operator, `[]`, has higher precedence than the cast operator.  As a result, you are reading the `itr`<sup>th</sup> byte of the data to which `buffer` points, converting that to type `int *`, converting the result implicitly to `int` (turn up your compiler's warning level if it's not already warning about that) and storing the final result in `data2`.  Probably passing through type `int *` as an intermediate form is effectively a no-op.

The simplest change you could make would be to insert parentheses to override the default operator precedence:

```
        data2[itr] = ((int*)buffer)[itr];
```

That converts `buffer` back to an `int *` first, and access the `itr`<sup>th</sup> *`int`* to which it points, which is what you want.

Personally, however, if I were relying on the argument to actually be an `int *` but could not update the parameter type formally (but somehow could nevertheless modify the function implementation) then I would create a correctly-typed copy as the very first thing I did:

```
void disp(char *buffer) {
    int *int_buffer = (int *) buffer;
```

Then I could later just do

```
    // ...

        data2[itr] = int_buffer[itr];

    // ...
```

and generally conduct business almost as if I had been able to set the parameter type appropriately.

Alternatively, for this particular use, you have the option of simply performing a bulk copy:

```
    memcpy(data2, buffer, 5 * sizeof(*data2));
```

Done, except for printing out the result.

Answer (score 1):

Use for example this statement in the function

```
data2[itr] = *(int*)( buffer + itr * sizeof( int  ) );
```

Otherwise as the `buffer` has the type `char *` then in general the expression `buffer[itr]` does not point to a correctly aligned object of the type `int`.

Or as `@n. 'pronouns' m` pointed in a comment you can use this statement

```
data2[itr] = ((int*)buffer )[itr];
```

that in fact is the same.

That is you need to apply correctly the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Huh? `((int*)buffer)[itr];`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Or this expression can be used.

Answer (score 1):

As you know you are sending int array to the function, you can safely cast it to int *

```
void disp(char *buffer)
{
    int *intBuffer = (int *) buffer;
    int itr, data2[5];

    for ( itr=0; itr < 5; itr++)
    {
        data2[itr] = intBuffer[itr];

        printf("data2[%d]= %d\n", itr, data2[itr]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `data1` is `int[5]`, an array of five `int`. You can declare a pointer to it as `int (*)[5]`.

### See this code, changed from your `disp()` code

```
void _disp(char* buffer)
{
    int(*original)[5] = (int(*)[5])(buffer);
    int data2[50];

    for (int itr = 0; itr < 5; itr += 1)
    {
        data2[itr] = (*original)[itr];
        printf("data2[%d]= %d\n", itr, data2[itr]);
    };
};
```

### It shows

```
Using (*)[5]

data2[0]= 10
data2[1]= 20
data2[2]= 30
data2[3]= 40
data2[4]= 50
```

### for this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void _disp(char*);

int main(void)
{
    int data1[5] = { 10,20,30,40,50 };
    printf("\nUsing (*)[5]\n\n");
    _disp((char*)data1);
    return 0;
}

void _disp(char* buffer)
{
    int(*original)[5] = (int(*)[5])(buffer);
    int data2[50];

    for (int itr = 0; itr < 5; itr += 1)
    {
        data2[itr] = (*original)[itr];
        printf("data2[%d]= %d\n", itr, data2[itr]);
    };
};
```

[Compiled just under MSVC 19.27]

### An arguably cleaner and more flexible way

This code works too

```
void _disp2(char* buffer)
{
    int*    pInt = (int*)buffer;
    int     data2[50];

    for (int itr = 0; itr < 5; itr += 1)
    {
        data2[itr] = *(pInt + itr);
        printf("data2[%d]= %d\n", itr, data2[itr]);
    };
};
```

Here we just cast `buffer` to an `(int*)` and use arithmetic to copy the values, as it will be one after another in memory anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. Use a union and a pointer, rather than type casting.

```
void disp(char *buffer)
{
int itr, data2[5];
for(itr=0;itr<5;itr++)
{
    data2[itr]=(int*)buffer[itr];
    printf("data2[%d]= %d\n",itr,data2[itr]);
}
}
/* Becomes */
void disp(char *buffer)
{
 union tag1 {
    char * cptr;
    int * iptr;
 } u;
int * itrp = NULL;  /* or null or even nil depending
                              on compiler headers...*/
int itr, data2[5];
u.cptr = buffer; /*in as char*   */
itrp = u.iptr;    /*out as int*  */

 for(itr=0;itr<5;itr++)
 {
    data2[itr]= itrp++;
    printf("data2[%d]= %d\n",itr,data2[itr]);
 }
}
```